# Sorting an array using subscripts without moving array elements

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, mergesort

I have to sort an array of non-negative ints using mergesort in C, but there's a catch - I cant move around the actual array elements, like if I have {3,5,6,7,0,4,1,2}, the desired output should be

First element is at subscript: 4

0 3 5

1 5 2

2 6 3

3 7 -1

4 0 6

5 4 1

6 1 7

7 2 0

See how the ordering of the original input stays the same but only the keys get swapped as the numbers are compared? So far, my main functions are:

```
void Merge(int *A,int *L,int leftCount,int *R,int rightCount) 

{

    int i,j,k;

    // i - to mark the index of left sub-array (L)
    // j - to mark the index of right sub-array (R)
    // k - to mark the index of merged sub-array (A)
    i = 0; j = 0; k =0;

    while(i<leftCount && j< rightCount)
    {
        if(L[i]  <=  R[j])
        {
            //something important;
             i++;
        }
        else
        {
            //something important;
            j++;
        }
    }

    i=0;
    j=0;
    while(i < leftCount) A[k++] = L[i++]; //merge all input sequences without swapping initial order

    while(j < rightCount) A[k++] = R[j++];

}

// Recursive function to sort an array of integers.
void MergeSort(int *A,int n) 

{

    int mid,i,k, *L, *R;

    if(n < 2)
    {
       return; 
    }


    mid = n/2;  // find the mid index.

    // create left and right subarrays
    // mid elements (from index 0 till mid-1) should be part of left sub-array
    // and (n-mid) elements (from mid to n-1) will be part of right sub-array
    L = (int*)malloc(mid*sizeof(int));
    R = (int*)malloc((n- mid)*sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0;i<mid;i++) L[i] = A[i]; // creating left subarray
    for(i = mid;i<n;i++) R[i-mid] = A[i]; // creating right subarray

    MergeSort(L,mid);  // sorting the left subarray
    MergeSort(R,n-mid);  // sorting the right subarray
    Merge(A,L,mid,R,n-mid);  // Merging L and R into A as sorted list.
        free(L);
        free(R);
}
```

I know that I have to initialize the index of all the elements as -1 at the bottom of the recursion tree when there are only single elements during the merge-sort. And then I have to change those indices accordingly as I compare array elements from Left array vs Right array. But thats where Im stuck. My professor told the class to use a linked list - but Im having a tough time visualizing HOW i can implement a linked list to achieve this indexing thing. I dont want my homework to be done by someone else, I just want someone to explain in pseudocode how I should go about it, and then I can write the actual code myself. But Im so lost, Im sorry if the question is poorly asked, but Im brand spanking new here and Im freaking out :(

Comment: This isn't really an answer, so a comment: 1) linked lists and arrays are very different. 2) the typical way of sorting an array without moving the objects is to have an array of references (pointers or indexes) to the objects, and then sort that based on the objects pointed to.  The original objects stay in their original locations, but you can traverse them in sorted order by using the reference array. 3) if you are using linked lists, then the order is defined by the links between them, you can modify the references to change the order. --- so, are you working with arrays or a linked list?

Comment: I like the idea of using an array of references to point to the actual input array elements, but the professor has said we need to use a linked list. But I dont see how a linked list would work in helping me keep track of the locations of the input sequence. Btw, thank you so much for commenting!

Comment: One single linked list appears strange to me. If at all, I could imagine you create several linked lists, each of them containing the already sorted sub-sequences, and with each step, you merge two linked lists into one...

Comment: @Aconcagua that is the idea. a linked list is, like an array, a reference to the beginning.  To keep track of the sublists, you create pointers to them, which effectively creates new linked lists.  By removing the reference to them from the 'parent' you do indeed end up with two seperate lists.  That is largely redundant though, as you will be modifying those pointers anyway when you 'move' the list items.  My answer goes into more detail - look at the item pointed to by pointer #1 - I don't ever care where it points to, so there is no point 'breaking' the link to the next item...

Comment: ... I do 'break' the final reference at the end of the sublists though, because once you have begun, you can then just check for a null pointer, instead of keeping track of sublist length.  All in all, what we are doing is, as I said in my original comment, only changing the links/references/pointers, and not moving the items, or copying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. lets start with a simple example, a list of 4 elements to sort, lets go through the process of what your function needs to do and how it does it in terms of linked lists:

```
#->[3]->[1]->[4]->[2]->$
```

Ok, so here # is your pointer to the first element, in this case `[3]`, which has a pointer to the second, and so on. I shall use `->$` as a null pointer (not pointing to anything) and `->*` as a 'I don't care' pointer (where a pointer may exist, but want to show a conceptional break in the list)

We now perform multiple passes to merge these into one sorted list.

This is the first pass, so we treat it as if we have multiple lists of length `1`:

```
#->* [3]->* [1]->* [4]->* [2]->*
```

In reality, these remain linked for now, but this is the conceptional model.

so what to we need 'know' at this time?

1. the end of the list before list #1
2. reference to beginning of list #1
3. reference to beginning of list #2
4. reference to item after list #2

Then we merge the two sublists (2) and (3) onto the end of (1), by taking the minimum of the heads of the lists, detaching that, and ammending it to (1), moving onto the next value in that list if it exists

conceptional

```
//sublists length 1. we'll work on the first pair
#->* [3]->* [1]->* [4]->* [2]->*  

//smallest element from sublists added to new sublist
#->* [3]->*        [4]->* [2]->*  //
     [1]->*

//above repeated until sublists are both exhausted
#->*               [4]->* [2]->*
     [1]->[3]->*

//we now have a sorted sublist
#->* [1]->[3]->*   [4]->* [2]->*
```

actual

```
//(1-4) are pointers to the list as per description above
#->[3]->[1]->[4]->[2]->$
|   |    |    |
1   2    3    4

//set the end of the lists (2) and (3) to point to null, so 
//when we reach this we know we have reached the end of the 
//sublist (integrity remains because of pointers (1-4)
#->* [3]->$ [1]->$ [4]->[2]->$
|     |      |      |
1     2      3      4

//the smallest (not null) of (2) and (3) is referenced by (1), 
//update both pointers (1) and (2) or (3) to point to the next
//item
#->[1]->* [3]->$ $ [4]->[2]->$
    |       |    |  |
    1       2    3  4

//repeat until both (2) and (3) point to null   
#->[1]->[3]->* $ $ [4]->[2]->$
         |     | |  |
         1     2 3  4
```

We now have a linked list with the first sublist in it.  Now, we keep track of (1), and move on to the second pair of sublists, starting with (4), repeating the process.

Once (2),(3) and (4) are all null, we have completed the pass.  We now have sorted sublists, and a single linked list again:

```
#->[1]->[3]->[2]->[4]->$ $ $ $
                   |     | | |
                   1     2 3 4
```

Now we do the same, only with sublists twice the length. (and repeat)

The list is sorted when sublist length >= length of linked list.

At no point during this have we actually moved any data around, only modified the links between the items in the linked list.

This should give you a solid idea of what you need to do from here.

I've extended this to some actual code:

<kbd>[See it here](http://ideone.com/r39lvU)</kbd>

I wrote it in python, so it satisfies your desire for pseudocode, as it isn't code for the language that you are writing in.

pertinent function with additional comments:

```
def mergesort(unsorted):
  #dummy start node, python doesn't have pointers, but we can use the reference in here in the same way
    start = llist(None)
    start.append(unsorted)
    list_length = unsorted.length()
    sublist_length = 1
    #when there are no sublists left, we are sorted
    while sublist_length < list_length:
        last  = start
        sub_a = start.next
        #while there are unsorted sublists left to merge
        while sub_a:
            #these cuts produce our sublists (sub_a and sub_b) of the correct length
            #end is the unsorted content
            sub_b = sub_a.cut(sublist_length)
            end   = sub_b.cut(sublist_length) if sub_b else None
            #I've written this so is there are any values to merge, there will be at least one in sub_a
            #This means I only need to check sub_a
            while sub_a:
                #sort the sublists based on the value of their first item
                sub_a, sub_b = sub_a.order(sub_b)
                #cut off the smallest value to add to the 'sorted' linked list
                node = sub_a
                sub_a = sub_a.cut(1)
                last = last.append(node)
                #because we cut the first item out of sub_a, it might be empty, so swap the references if so
                #this ensures that sub_a is populated if we want to continue
                if not sub_a:
                  sub_a, sub_b = sub_b, None
            #set up the next iteration, pointing at the unsorted sublists remaining
            sub_a = end
        #double the siblist size for the next pass
        sublist_length *=2
    return start.next
```

Comment: wow i really appreciate the time and effort you put in to explain this to me - it really helps a lot. I checked out the actual python code, and it sorts the actual input array elements by moving them around. How would I extrapolate from this code to code where the input element sequence remains the same, yet some array of indexes get swapped and map the smallest to the largest in the original array?

Comment: Actually, python handles object acess and passing by object references, which are (roughly) equivalent to pointers. The biggest difference is that you don't have quite the flexibility of pointers so I had to use the dummy start node.  Lines like `sub_a, sub_b = sub_a.order(sub_b)` are not actually moving the objects around in memory.  The C equivalent here would be something like: `if (lista->data > listb->data) { llist * listtemp = lista; lista = listb; listb = listtemp;}` (with some checking that the pointers are not `null` of course). That swaps the pointers to two list items.

Comment: `node = sub_a; sub_a = sub_a.cut(1)` likewise doesn't make a copy of the list or the list item referenced by `sub_a`, instead it is equivalent to; `llist * node = lista; lista = node->next; node->next = null;`, that is, it is just pointer assignment, changing the references to change the order, without moving the data itself.  Think of it like a collection of people standing together, all pointing at someone else, you can follow that to travel between them. get a few of them to point in a different direction, and you visit them in a different order. but they havent moved. @Clueless

Answer (score 0):

Create a linked list of items whereby each list item has both the value and index of each array item. So aside from prev/next, each item in  the linked list is a struct that has struct members `uint value;` and `uint index;` .

Pre-populate the link-list just by iterating the array and for each array element, append a new linked-list item to the list and set the value and index of the array element in each linked-list item as they are added to the list.

Use the pre-populated linked-list as a "proxy" for the actual array values and sort the linked list as if it were the original array. I.e. instead of sorting based on `myArray[i]`, sort based on `currentLinkListItem.value` .

Comment: This is *selection sort*!

Answer (score 0):

As speaking of linked lists:

```
typedef struct ValueNode
{
    struct ValueNode* next;
    int* value;
} ValueNode;

typedef struct ListNode
{
    struct ListNode* next;
    ValueNode* value;
} ListNode;
```

Singly linked lists are sufficient...

Now first the merge algorithm:

```
ValueNode* merge(ValueNode* x, ValueNode* y)
{
    // just assuming both are != NULL...
    ValueNode dummy;
    ValueNode* xy = &dummy;
    while(x && y)
    {
        ValueNode** min = *x->value < *y->value ? &x : &y;
        xy->next = *min;
        *min = (*min)->next;
        xy = xy->next;
    }
    // just append the rest of the lists - if any...
    if(x)
    {
        xy->next = x;
    }
    else if(y)
    {
        xy->next = y;
    }
    return dummy.next;
}
```

The dummy is just for not having to check the for NULL within the loop...

Now let's use it:

```
int array[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 0, 4, 1, 2 };
ListNode head;
ListNode* tmp = &head;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); ++i)
{
    // skipping the normally obligatory tests for result being 0...
    ValueNode* node = (ValueNode*) malloc(sizeof(ValueNode));
    node->value = array + i;
    node->next = NULL;
    tmp->next = (ListNode*) malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    tmp = tmp->next;
    tmp->value = node;
}
tmp->next = NULL;
```

Now we have set up a list of lists, each containing one single element. Now we merge pairwise two subsequent lists. We need to pay attention: If we merge two lists into one, keep it as the new head and merge the next one into it, and so on, then we would have implemented selection sort! So we need to make sure that we do not touch an already merged array before all others are merged. That is why the next step looks a little complicated...

```
while(head.next->next) // more than one single list element?
{
    tmp = head.next;
    while(tmp)
    {
        ListNode* next = tmp->next;
        if(next)
        {
            // we keep the merged list in the current node:
            tmp->value = merge(tmp->value, next->value);
            // and remove the subsequent node from it:
            tmp->next = next->next;
            free(next);
        }
        // this is the important step:
        // tmp contains an already merged list
        // -> we need to go on with the NEXT pair!
        tmp = tmp->next;
        // additionally, if we have an odd number of lists,
        // thus at the end no next any more, we set tmp to NULL,
        // too, so we will leave the loop in both cases...
    }
}
```

Finally, we could print the result; note that we only have one single linked list left within your outer linked list:

```
ValueNode* temp = head.next->value;
while(temp)
{
    printf("%d\n", *temp->value);
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

What is yet missing is freeing the allocated memory - I'll leave that to you...